# DISQUS identifier only changes the thread in some cases

Tags: javascript, html, disqus

I have this code that I took from a blog post somehwere:

http://pastebin.com/fidyNMtX

What it basically does is that is makes two links that when clicked load a DISQUS box beneath them. The point it to have more than one DISQUS per page and this is a one way of doing it.

Now, this works. Each link shows a DIFFERENT thread since one link has "luka" as an ID and the other has jakoduginizznakova2. But if I for example use "luka1" and "luka2" it loads the same thread. This isn't really acceptable in my situation since I want to use a post id as the identifier and those numbers are really close.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Both identifiers are being assigned to the same URL. In order to create a unique thread, you'll need to set a different disqus_url variable as well.

Additional information on Disqus embed variables: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables

DISQUS.reset code sample: https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/html/disqus_reset.html